# Rails 3 Delete Confirmation not Displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

I have the following in a namespace enviroment.

This is in my Article Index File to delete an Article.

```
 <%=button_to "Delete", admin_article_path(article), :class => 'button', :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete%>
```

However it deletes the record but the confirmation does not come up.

Any ideas why? or have i got this wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: <form action="/admin/articles/2" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" /><input class="button" data-confirm="Are you sure?" type="submit" value="Delete" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="s0jDuHYuHSbq9MEIEOvEFwq005/1dH03D75FfJnlwgw=" /></div></form>

Comment: Try `<%=button_to "Delete", admin_article_path(article), {:class => 'button', :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete} %>`. If it works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: That is also not working

Comment: ...huh. Just realised it fails on my Rails 3 app too. I'll try to look into it.

Comment: Made some progress. Are you using jQuery or Prototype as your javascript library?

Comment: using jQuery for my apps

Comment: Hmm, sorry, my bug appears to be Prototype related. Does your head a) include all necessary javascripts (including rails.js); and b) contain `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your included javascripts include rails.js (usually, this means making sure rails.js is in `app/assets/javascripts`, since `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` will likely include the entire tree).

Also, make sure that the `<head>` tag of your layout contains `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`.